# Changing stream metadata and converting at the same time in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, metadata

I'm trying to convert an HEVC (h265) video into h264, while at the same time adding the 'rotate' key to the video stream metadata. I have tried:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v libx264 -metadata:s:v rotate="90" out.mp4`

This converts the video to h264 properly, but doesn't add the rotation metadata.

All posts I've read online about changing the rotation metadata include `-c copy` in their command, which I obviously can't do since I'm converting between codecs.

Is there any way to do both the conversion, and add the metadata in one command? Any help is appreciated.